# Containing type does not implement interface when trying to explicitly define a method

Tags: c#, interface

```
    interface eer {

        public abstract void S1<T>(T? t) where T : struct;
        public abstract void S1<T>(T? t) ;
    }

    class A1 : eer {

        void eer.S1<T>(T? t){}
        void eer.S1<T>(T? t)where T:default{}
    }

    class B1 : A1 {

        void eer.S1<T>(T? t) { }  //error
        void eer.S1<T>(T? t) where T : default { }  //error
    }
```

So my `B1` class implements the `eer` interface *indirectly* but when I try to explicitly implement the `S1<T>(T? t) where T : struct` and `S1<T>(T? t)` methods inside `B1` I get the error stating that the containing type does not implement the `eer` interface.

I am guessing this is beacuse in some situation there would be some ambiguity maybe.
Could you please tell me why is that so (It does not make sense to me now)?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to `B1` the `eer` interface. The explanation is that `A1` must implement the `eer` interface, but the  `B1` has nothing to do with it. When u wanted to implement the methods in the explicit mode (eer.S1) the `B1` doesn't know that u want to implement `eer` interface because it was not defined for  the `B1` class.

```
 class B1 : A1, eer
 {

     void eer.S1<T>(T? t) { }  //error
     void eer.S1<T>(T? t) where T : default { }  //error
 }
```